# Trying to display two unordered lists on the same line with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It always displays on two lines no matter what I change. There is a probably an easier way to do this without flexbox, but I want to learn how to do it with the flexbox properties.

My desired outcome would be to display the first unordered list on the left,and the second on the far right(end) on the same line.

```css
.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.leftNav {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.rightNav {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <div class="leftNav">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li><a href="">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rightNav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like just declaring navigation as a flex element does the trick, without any further flex settings. Worth to notice that it behaves this way since the row direction is the default one.

Regarding `flex-wrap`, it is not really necessary here at all, since there's not that much content that it would wrap (or wouldn't, depending on your aims). Here's a [nice pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj0Py.png) from mozilla demonstrating the use of `flex-wrap`.

`justify-content` is the property that is need to be set for the whole flex group, either. Here's [the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejf2A.png) demonstrating the use.

---

I believe you would like the left nav to stick to the left and the right nav to stick to the right. In this case you just specify the `justify-content: space-between;`, as I explained a couple of sentences earlier.

```css
.navigation{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="navigation">
    <div class="leftNav">
      <ul>
       <li>Menu</li>
       <li><a href="">One</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rightNav">  
      <ul>
       <li><a href="">My Account</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you.This helped but i got one more problem the .rightNav {
  justify-content: flex-end;} doesnt work.And if you could explain which items need the display flexbox property.beacuse if i remove it from the unordered lists it wont work anymore.

Comment: @Davor the flex-end isn't doing what you believe it should. Look at the update of my answer. So, you would like the right nav to stick to the right?

Comment: Ahh I think I understand now,every element needs to have the display:flex; property to use the flexbox properties not just the parent.Right?Beacuse adding the display:flex; to the .rightNav {
  justify-content: flex-end;} worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

https://jsfiddle.net/cec5wqv5/5/

HTML

```
<body>
<header>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <div class="leftNav">
      <ul>
       <li>Menu</li>
       <li><a href="">One</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rightNav">  
      <ul>
       <li><a href="">My Account</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.navigation{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 8px;
}
```